# highlight the row before month of domain expiry using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to highlight the row before month of domain expiry based on the TH Date and time as `<td>2017-04-14 17:21:00</td>` using javascript or jquery

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Domain</th>
    <th>Renewal Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.com</td>
    <td>2017-04-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-08-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Why do you need Jquery or Javascript to highlight a row ? Why not use styling or css ?

Comment: i don't know how can i highlight the row automatically by javascript or  jquery please help me

Comment: I think the OP wants to highlight a domain's row when today's date is a month or less from the expiration date.

Comment: Loop over the rows, select the td, read the text, convert it to a date, figure out if it is month away, set css class.

Comment: i don't know how because i don't have good experience in javascript

Comment: So you want to highlight all <td> that has a date in it?

Comment: yes exactly @repzero

Comment: @repzero Edward is a bit confusing. Based on Eric's answer and comments, the OP wants to highlight a domain's row when today's date is a month or less from the expiration date.

Comment: how to do this the user epascarello pointed out. @Edward you should dive more into jQuery selectors (xpath) and setting classes in javascript

Comment: @Edward I revised by post based on question revision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we're doing:

1. Create a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype) object for today.
2. Get all `td` that have a date. Currently determined by being the second `td`.
3. Get the expire date and create a `Date` object with that string.
4. Create a `Date` object for a month from now by using the `Date` object for today and add 1 month to that date.
5. Check to see if the expire date is prior to today or within the next month and assign appropriate highlight class.
6. Check if highlight has been set, if so, add the class to the element.

Please note that this solution adds two different highlights.

1. Expire dates within a month from now.
2. Expired dates.

```js
var today     = new Date(),
    toISO8601 = function ( dateStr, offset ) {
        return dateStr.replace( ' ', 'T' ) + ( offset ? offset : 'Z' );
    };

$( 'td:nth-child( 2 )' ).each( function( i, el ) {

  var $el       = $( el ),
      expireStr = toISO8601( $.trim( $el.text() ), '-05:00' ),
      expires   = new Date( expireStr ),
      inAMonth  = new Date( today.getTime() ),
      highlight;
      
  inAMonth.setMonth( inAMonth.getMonth() + 1 );

  highlight = expires < today ? 'has-expired' :
              expires < inAMonth ? 'about-to-expire' :
              false;
                  
  if ( highlight ) {
  
    $el
      .parent()
      .addClass( highlight );
      
  }  

} );
```

```css
.has-expired {
  background-color: indianred;
}
.about-to-expire {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Domain</th>
    <th>Renewal Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.com</td>
    <td>2017-04-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-08-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-04-15 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2018-06-28 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-04-17 10:21:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), i.e. `expires.toISOString()`, instead of my `toISO8601()` method but `toISOString()` will return the time in UTC where my function allows you to determine the the offset for your own timezone (with fallback to UTC).

Time can be a tricky thing to handle and depending on your needs you might need a library like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: i have mac and i work in all internet browsers expect Safari is not show any color

Comment: Does the code snippet on this page work in Safari? **Yes** or **no**?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox are more forgiving of the date string passed to `Date`. You will need to format you string to [RFC2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) or [ISO-8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). The easiest will probably be ISO-8601. I'll update my answer to my timezone CDT (5 hours behind UTC/GMT).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an id to the element you want to change so can access it in your javascript code:

```
<tr>
    <td id="expiryDate">mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-08-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
   expiryDate = document.getElementById("expiryDate");
  // convert expiryDate.innerHTML to date and check if it's within a month is so do:
   expiryDate.innerHTML = "<mark>" + expiryDate.innerHTML + "</mark>"
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric i want java script highlight the row based on the TD date and time like <td>2017-04-14 17:21:00</td>

Comment: Okay, I understand that now, could you please make that more clear in your question so others know it as well :)

Comment: :) sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

A javascript solution (answer edited as a result in edit in question)

First add a class tag named `"date"` to all `td` cell that has a date.

```js
//get all cells with date
today_date = new Date()
expiration_date = new Date().setFullYear(2100, 01, 14)
all_date_td = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
//loop over each html elements
for (var x = 0; x < all_date_td.length; ++x) {
  var content = all_date_td[x].innerHTML;
  year = Number(content.replace(/[ ].*/, "").split(/-| /)[0])
  month = Number(content.replace(/[ ].*/, "").split(/-| /)[1].replace("0", ""))
  day = Number(content.replace(/[ ].*/, "").split(/-| /)[2].replace("0", ""))
  expiration_date = new Date()
  expiration_date.setFullYear(year, month, day)
  if (today_date < expiration_date) {
    all_date_td[x].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Domain</th>
    <th>Renewal Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.com</td>
    <td class="date">2017-04-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td class="date">2017-08-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td class="date">2015-08-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @repzero, it's highlight all the dates? not before one month

Comment: I haven't seen Edward mentioned that piece you info in his question...he should if it that he wants....see the question I ask him before i post my answer

Comment: @edward yes it highlight all the dates, something else you are looking for?

Comment: @repzero please can you fix that for me?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a JS function that will:

1. Iterate the relevant dom elements (the ones that hold the date text) and get their text value
2. Create a date object from each date text and compare it to today's date
3. If the difference between two dates is less than a month add a highlight css class to the parent tr element of the td element that you're checking
4. Make sure that the highlight css class is defined as you want
5. Run the JS function on document ready

Answer (score 0):

Run the below example. Cheers...!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tr").each(function(i) {
    var _this = $(this);
    if (i != 0) {
      var selectDate = $(_this).children("td").eq(1).text();
      if (Date.parse($.trim(selectDate)) < Date.parse(new Date())) {
        $(_this).addClass('highlight');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #ffdd00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Domain</th>
    <th>Renewal Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.com</td>
    <td>2017-04-14 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.net</td>
    <td>2017-02-19 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.org</td>
    <td>2017-08-16 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.edu</td>
    <td>2017-02-15 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mydomain.co.in</td>
    <td>2017-08-22 17:21:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe the first row should be highlighted. As I understand it the OP wants to highlight a domain's row when today's date is a month or less from the expiration date in the row. This only highlights dates prior to today.

Comment: Thank you very much @hungerstar, the highlight don't work on safari and it's highlight after expiry date it should be before expiry date and thanks again for help

Comment: Thank you very much @Shakthi, the highlight don't work on safari and it's highlight after expiry date it should be before expiry date and thanks again for help